# Keybind to show album art in ncmpcpp?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, audio-player

Sometimes I like to quickly see the album art of the music I am listening to. How can I set up a macro for this in [ncmpcpp](https://github.com/ncmpcpp/ncmpcpp)? I would like to use an external command like feh. Isn't there something like `:exec-external-command feh %directory%/art.jpg`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not too sure about you but I never have the album art from my music as a separate file, though I do know that you can "extract" the art from the audio file itself. The shell script below takes the song, turns it into a image, then opens it in feh. You will have to change out the directory I used with the music directory used for mpd, but it does work.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Requires mpc

almost=$(mpc --format %file%)

echo "$almost" >> /home/apple/Music/some_stuff.txt

name=$(head -n 1 /home/apple/Music/some_stuff.txt)

rm /home/apple/Music/some_stuff.txt

ffmpeg -i "/home/apple/Music/$name" /home/apple/Music/image.jpg

feh -S filename /home/apple/Music/image.jpg

rm /home/apple/Music/image.jpg
```

Add a keybind that would execute the script and there you go.